# For z complex, if $|z| = 1$, can I bound the number $2$ like this,

Tags: complex-analysis

If $z$ is complex and $|z|=1$, is this bound true:

$$2 < |cz^2+1|$$

for $c>2$.

Thanks,

Comment: Let $z=\cos t+i\sin t$ . For real $c$ ,the inequality holds for all  $z$ iff  $c>3-\cos 2t$ for all real $t$, iff  $c>4$.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, if $c=\frac 52$ and $z=i$ then $cz^2+1=1-c=-\frac 32$

Comment: Thanks for the nice and simple counterexample, @ThomasAndrews :-)

Answer (score 0):

We want to look at
$$
2 < \lvert cz^2+1 \rvert =: \lvert u \rvert
$$
The argument $u$ can be written because of $\lvert z \rvert = 1$ as
$$
u = cz^2+1 = c (e^{i\phi})^2 + 1 = c e^{2i\phi} + 1 \quad (\phi \in [0,2\pi)) 
$$
its length can be expressed via the complex conjugate:
$$
\bar{u} = c e^{-2i\phi} + 1 \\
\lvert u \rvert^2 =
u \bar{u} = c^2+1+c(e^{2i\phi} + e^{-2i\phi})
= c^2+1+2c \cos(2\phi) \in [ (c-1)^2, (c+1)^2 ]
$$
so
$$
\lvert u \rvert \in [ c-1, c+1 ]
$$
we had $c > 2$, so 
$$
\lvert u \rvert \in [ a, b ]
$$
with $a > 1$ and $b > 3$. Alas that might allow values $\lvert u \rvert < 2$.